# WCF, ASP.NET sharing session when WCF is called from flash

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, wcf, session

I've followed the advice in various places, including other questions posted on stackoverflow about sharing the session state between a WCF service and an ASP.NET website, but cannot get my specific scenario to work:

The website and WCF service are both virtual directories of the same application in IIS 7 and both share an app pool.  The website stores some data into the session.  A flash object rendered on the client makes a call to the WCF service.  I would like the WCF service to be able to access the data in the session.

I have put the [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)] attribute on the service class, and I have the following lines in the web.config for the service:

and on the binding I have allowCookies="true".

All server side code is written in C#.

However, when using HttpContext.Current.Session from the WCF service, I find that there are no keys stored in the session object.

I have checked with Fiddler, and the flash object definitely passes through the ASP.NET_SessionId with the same value as requests to the website from the browser use.

Can anyone shed any light onto how I can make this scenario work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx**

Comment: Read it already.  I want instance of service per request to be able to share the web session.